# javascript worked on local server but not in live server 2

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my complete code
I tried many of code in checksum but does not work on Nextraone server.

Javascript worked on local server but not in live server.

I loaded some js in local and in live. Js loaded perfectly in both server but don't know why my js is not working in live server. This is the list of js that I loaded in both servers.

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.amount').keyup(function() {
      calculateTotal(this);
    });
  });

  function calculateTotal(src) {
    var sum = 0,
      tbl = $(src).closest('table');
    tbl.find('input.amount').each(function(index, elem) {
      var val = parseFloat($(elem).val());
      if (!isNaN(val)) {
        sum += val;
      }
    });
    tbl.find('.total').html(sum.toFixed(2));
  }
</script>



<table border="1">

  <tr>
    <td>Amount 1</td>
    <td><input class="amount" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Amount 2</td>
    <td><input class="amount" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Amount 3</td>
    <td><input class="amount" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Total Amount</td>
    <td><span class="total">0</span></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: No errors? You can press F12 in the browser and see if there are any errors in the console.

Comment: Improved wording and grammar.

Comment: Install firebug and check in console. 
Click on Network and check all dependency like JS, CSS, images everything laded properly which you expect to be in order. 
Check in Errors,Info, Warning etc from console

Are you using any external JS? 
Clear browser cache, history with offline data also and refresh browser. You will get some hint. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check dependency like jquery loads on server too